# Python Pivot dataframe without adding spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The script below gets stock data and does calculates statistics on the price delta. My issue is in doing the pivot correctly The pivot function works but it creates unnecessary empty cells. Ideally I would like the pivot to pivot and all the data points be on a single row.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

    
slv = yf.Ticker("SLV")
slvhist = slv.history(period="1mo")

slvhist['delta'] = slvhist['Close'] - slvhist['Open']

perc =[.25, .50, .75, .99]
include =['object', 'float', 'int'] 
slvhist['delta'].describe(percentiles = perc, include = include)


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'StockCompare': slvhist['delta'].describe(percentiles = 

perc, include = include)})
df2.loc['stock'] = ['SLV']

df2['Metics'] = df2.index
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)

dfp = df2.pivot(columns='Metics', values='StockCompare').assign(g = 0).groupby('g').max().reset_index().drop(columns='g')
```

Here is the result of my pivot. The values are scatterd. They should all be in row 0 as 1 row with all values.
[image]

Comment: Please show examples of what your code returns and what you expect it to return.

Comment: Thank you ipj yes that was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try following transformations:

```
dfp = df2.pivot(columns='Metics', values='StockCompare').assign(g = 0).groupby('g').max().reset_index().drop(columns='g')
```

result:

```
Metics   25%   50%    75%    99%  count   max      mean  min      std
0      -0.12  0.14  0.425  1.385   23.0  1.55  0.031739 -1.9  0.69405
```

This will make statistics more readable.

Changing a little previous code we can obtain similar result even simpler:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'StockCompare': slvhist['delta'].describe(percentiles = perc, include = include)})
df2.T
```

output:

```
              count      mean      std  min   25%   50%    75%    99%   max
StockCompare   23.0  0.031739  0.69405 -1.9 -0.12  0.14  0.425  1.385  1.55
```